# TinyMCE Adding html tags to database

Tags: php, tinymce

I have a form on a web page that has TinyMCE integrated. Im posting whatever is written in the text box to the database. But tinyMCE is posting all html tags to the database. I have used the php strip_tags but if I use this I'll loose the features of colours and bold text that tinymce outputs.

Is there a way to allow to keep tinyMCE features like colour text etc on output but keep the database clean from html tags?

Comment: Use Markdown instead of TinyMCE. Markdown is what this site is using.

Comment: why do you use tinymce then? tinymce is used to edit html content and the content gets wrapped inside html elements

Answer (score 1):

Use the `strip_tags`-function. You can define allowable tags:

```
strip_tags($text, '<b><a>');
```

Comment: Im using this form to add posts to a database for a search engine. If I allow certain html tags then the search engine will pick up on the the html tags which i dont want to happen when someone searches for something.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to configure TinyMCE to only allow the elements you want:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    valid_elements : "strong/b,em/i,font"
});
```

Or something similar.

For mroe info: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements